# JWT as part of the HTTP header

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, jwt

Why is it a good practice to send JWT as part of the HTTP header? Many articles seem to suggest that but don't explain the reason. Is there a security risk in embedding JWT within the HTTP body? If  yes, how is header more secure than body?

Comment: HTTP body is often used by any other data. At the second you can not send body in GET request.

Comment: Its a standard  bearer and token always sent in header because other application find tokens in headers not in body

Comment: There is actually a similar question here: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/130548/should-jwt-token-be-stored-in-a-cookie-header-or-body

Comment: it is not more secure. I think it is just a prefer way. Using cookie may works on browser app, but for server to server call it may be a bit trouble. Put it in url parameter looks ugly and url may be too long. Put it in request body works but you need to parse the content when it is needed. Put it as other header might be dropped by some proxy servers in the way, so using Authorization server is preferred and quite standard.

Answer (score 0):

You need to send this token as part of header because the header is responsible for the authorization data of the request, and not all of HTTP verbs accepts body in request.

Comment: Hi Vicenzo. What does it mean that the header is responsible for the authorization data of the request?

Comment: This part of the request must contain this information, it is its original purpose.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Authorization